# How to count string with pattern in series object?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose a data like this:

```
>>> data
                x
0   [wdq, sda, q]
1    [q, d, qasd]
2  [d, b, sdaaaa]
```

I wonder how many string contains `a` in each list, which means I need an answer like this:

```
>>> data
                x  count_a
0   [wdq, sda, q]        1
1    [q, d, qasd]        1
2  [d, b, sdaaaa]        1
```

How can I do this in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is a `pandas.DataFrame` and `x` is a `list` object:

```
df['count_a'] = df['x'].apply(lambda x: sum('a' in e for e in x))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this;

```
for i in my_series:
    print (i.count('a'))
```

this gives each your series letter

Answer (score 0):

To find out how many `String`s in each `List` contain the letter `a`, you can use the following:

```
l = ['wdq', 'sda', 'qaaa']

print(sum([1 for x in l if 'a' in x]))
```

This prints the following:

```
2
```

Comment: Actually, the variable `count_a` does not mean the time `a` appears. It means the time string contained `a` appears

Comment: @Garvey I now understand what you asked, and this is a solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['a', '12asf3', 'sdf']
b = ['gfdg5', '   ', 'vag gfd4']
c = [' fd4 ', 'sfsa fa', 'df4 a']

abc = [a, b, c]

for mem in abc:
  counter = 0
  for str in mem:
    if 'a' in str:
      counter += 1
  print abc.index(mem), mem, counter
```

Output:

```
0 ['a', '12asf3', 'sdf'] 2
1 ['gfdg5', '   ', 'vag gfd4'] 1
2 [' fd4 ', 'sfsa fa', 'df4 a'] 2
```